# Is it possible to declare a function type that uses itself as an argument in C++?

Tags: c++

For instance, is there any legal equivalent to this?

```
typedef void (*SelfReferencingFnPtr)(int, SelfReferencingFnPtr);
```

With clang, this causes the error "unknown name SelfReferencingFnPtr".

The best I was able to come up with is a functor whose `operator()` accepts its own type.

Comment: It would be a recursive definition, would it not?

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit, are we talking with respect to C++ syntax or about the general idea? Because it seems no more recursive than a struct with a pointer to itself.

Comment: Both. I disagree with your latter statement. This is more like a struct with an instance of itself. Surely? `typedef void(*abc)(int, void(*)(int, void(*)(int, void(*)(int, ...............`

Comment: That would be if you could pass functions as values, but they're always pointers. At a low level that could be implemented as a function accepting a function-pointer-sized thing as a last parameter, no? This can't be said of a struct with an instance of itself.

Comment: I was hoping for `auto foo () { return &foo; }` and `decltype(foo())`, but C++14 does not allow that. It seems to still be impossible.

Comment: @zne​​​​​​​​​​​ak: In terms of implementation, sure. But the analogy isn't direct; your question is instead about the type system, and I don't see how you can formulate a type to represent the function pointer you want.

Comment: I can't either and that's why I'm asking, but I still think that it makes some sort of sense. We had a little bit of both going on in the comments.

Comment: @zneak: Well, it doesn't. :) I think you're rendering too literally a comparison between function types and data objects. Anyway, you can only [properly] do it via proxy, which is what you already came up with (a functor).

Comment: No, it's impossible — the type would be infinite. It would be equivalent to a logical implication having itself as its antecedent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, see [GotW #57](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/057.htm). It's indeed a recursive problem.